# In ICS session-cookie error with using HttpUrlConnection

Tags: android, session-cookies, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, httpurlconnection

```
 MyApplication app = (MyApplication) mContext.getApplicationContext();

 CookieManager cookie = CookieManager.getInstance();                

    if(cookie.getCookie(mContext.getString(R.string.host_url))!=null){
    conn.setRequestProperty("Cookie",cookie.getCookie(mContext.getString(R.string.host_url)));                  app.cookie=cookie.getCookie(mContext.getString(R.string.host_url));
            }

  Map m = conn.getHeaderFields();
            if (m.containsKey("Set-Cookie")) {
                String cookies = "";
                Collection c = (Collection) m.get("Set-Cookie");
                for (Iterator i = c.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
                    cookies += (String) i.next() + ",";
                }
                cookie.setCookie(mContext.getString(R.string.host_url), cookies);
                Log.d("tag", "cookie set " +  cookies);
            }
```

-------------------make session with using cookie--------------------

```
          if (conn.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(),"UTF-8"));
                String line = null;
                String res = "";
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    res += line;
                }
                Log.d("tag", "url : " + requestUrl + "\n" + res);

                jobj = new JSONObject(res);
                if (jobj.getString("result").equals("YES")) {
                    success = true;
                } else if (jobj.getString("result").equals("NO")) {
                    result = jobj.getString("reason");
                }

                reader.close();
            }else{
                result = "HTTP FAILED";
            }
```

--------------get response in web---------------------

In ICS , this code not works.

when connect some .php in web, make session error
or other .php in web, conn.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK can`t catch the response.(result = "HTTP FAILED"; this case)

but, some .php file, is still work.

In android 2.2 or 2.3 is work well, but 4.0.4 NexusS,NexusGalaxy is in trouble.

is there any problem with my code? or the problem is for web?